# C++ Resizing String in String

Tags: c++, string, truncate

I am wondering why I cannot resize a string inside another string during a cout execution.
Here is the example of what I am trying to do, returning "expression must have integral or unscoped enum type"

```
string tipa = to_string((stod(taxa)+price)*0.2);
cout << "\nTip: $" + tipa.resize(tipa.size() - 4);
```

Here is an example of a solution I discovered by chance, but without knowing why:

```
string tipa = to_string((stod(taxa)+price)*0.2);
tipa.resize(tipa.size() - 4);
cout << "\nTip: $" + tipa;
```

Can someone explain this?

Comment: Because [`std::string::resize()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) is `void`…?

Comment: Neither of these should compile, and indeed [do not](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f5f4113e5a85e22). `resize` returns `void`.

Comment: Downvoted for lack of research effort, read the docs.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to remove the second resize portion of my solution, as it was copied and pasted from my error and not reviewed.

Answer (score 2):

The question is: What is the return type of [`std::string::resize()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/resize/)? If you look at the documentation, you'll see that it returns nothing! It returns a `void`.

So, the right way to call this is:

```
string tipa = to_string((stod(taxa)+price)*0.2);
tipa.resize(tipa.size() - 4); //you mutate the string here by resizing it, so the string inside it changes
cout << "\nTip: $" + tipa; //you print the string that was changed in the previous line
```

Honestly, I'm impressed that it even compiled. I don't know how that worked in the first place! You cannot `std::cout` a `void`!

I want to add, that realistically, cropping a floating-point number this way is bad. You should use `std::round` first, and then crop it. Consider the case if the length of `tipa` is less than 4. That code above will definitely crash.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a fatal error here:
According to the docs, [`std::basic_string::resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize):

> ## Return value
>
> (none)

And the signature for the function is:

```
void resize( size_type count );
```

Notice how the function is `void`, meaning you can't use it in a expression since it doesn't have a return value of [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

***EDIT***

Here is the correct way of using the function, the solution you found was terribly wrong:

```
string tipa = to_string((stod(taxa)+price)*0.2);
tipa.resize(tipa.size() - 4);
cout << "\nTip: $" + tipa;
```

Comment: Or just: `cout << "\nTip: $" + tipa.substr(0, tipa.size() - 4);`.